# Redirect to the same page in case of invalide url

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to redirect to the same page in case the user decides to enter an invalid url while he is on that page. What  I have so far is not working.  Is it even doable this way?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
  component: ResultsComponent,
  children: [
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'results' }]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write results name into path of ResultsComponent

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'results',
  component: ResultsComponent,
  children: [
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'results' }]}]
```

if you want to redirect same page call this where you reedirect

```
this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
this._router.navigate(['/same-route']);
```

Comment: it kind of works, meaning that it redirects to the same page BUT the page does not show the results anymore. The results are fetched from a database and the url contains queryParams if it helps

Comment: do u want to refresh page without reload page ?

Comment: I was trying for a refresh

Comment: Update answer check it